# Strange animation when moving last row out of section and deleting section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a multi-section tableview.  In edit mode I allow rows to be moved from one section to another.  Once the final row is removed from one section I delete that section. So I am using deleteSection inside moveRowAtIndexPath.

When the final item is moved from the section, the section header disappears as planned.  But there is a very strange animation bug, where the moved row seems to 'merge' with the row it is dropped above, and an empty row is displayed at the bottom of the 'to' section (probably because the numberOfRows for that section is correct, but 2 rows are in the same position).  Even stranger, when I click the reorder control for this row (not moving the item, simply touching and releasing), the two items 'unmerge'.

I have posted a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WorlOupeR6o) demonstrating this.

I have tried wrapping my data changes and view changes in begin/end updates, but to no avail.

I have uploaded a test project [here](http://www.madeinbletchley.com/TestSectionDelete.zip), and I will also post the code below.  A couple of points:

- I have tried to replicate my data source's format in the demo project, in case this is where the problem originates.  The key thing is that my source is a composite array of two other arrays (though I can't see why this would be an issue).
- To see the behavior in question, move the two rows in the bottom section, up into the top section.  Don't drop them in the last row on the top section though, since this seems to work ok.
- Moving rows the other way, from the top section to the bottom section, is buggy in this demo project.

**Code (all of this is in the demo project):**

I set up my arrays in loadView:

```
- (void)loadView{
array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[array1 addObject:@"test 0"];
[array1 addObject:@"test 1"];
[array1 addObject:@"test 2"];

    array2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array2 addObject:@"test a"];
    [array2 addObject:@"test b"];

    [super loadView];
}
```

I also have a method that returns a combination of these arrays - this is used as the data source:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sourceArray{
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
if (array1.count > 0) {
    [result addObject:array1];
}
if (array2.count >0) {
    [result addObject:array2];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which allows for very simple number of rows/sections:

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.sourceArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

Standard Cell/Header formatting:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %i", section];
}
```

**This is where I do the magic**

```
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *fromArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section]; 
    NSMutableArray *toArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.section];

    NSString *movedObject = [[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section] objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    [fromArray removeObject:movedObject];
    [toArray insertObject:movedObject atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

        if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: fromIndexPath.section] == 0) {
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting up your arrays in -loadView? You should only override -loadView if you're programmatically creating your view. No? And calling [super loadView] attempts to load a nib with the same name as the view controller in question. Why not move your array setup to -viewDidLoad?

Comment: Thanks - any links/more info on why this is so/where this rule comes from?  Doesn't help with my question of course, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: because loadView gets called by the OS if you are setting up your view in a nib. The documentation for the method explicitly states not to call this method directly and not to override if you are loading your view from a nib.

Comment: animation issue. see response below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that the row that comes from the to-be-deleted section is the one that disappears until you retouch the order control.

I suspect that when this datasource method is called by the tableview, its state is still in the middle of performing the move, so calling 'deleteSections' will make the table try and delete the row you're moving. It's not so much of a merge as the fact that it's fading away at the same rate as the section header, and the one below it is just scooting back up to fill the space.

Tapping the control causes the table view to rejigger itself and realize that the row isn't actually gone.

to try and work around this, try running the deletion in the next runloop, via a dispatch call, like:

```
if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: fromIndexPath.section] == 0) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    });
}
```

this will cause the deletion to run on the main thread still, but allow the 'moveRow' and whatever call stack it happens to be in finish up its logic before the deletion call

Comment: Thanks.  How does this compare as a solution vs using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?  Is there any pros/cons of either?
PS I think there is a ); missing - it's too small an edit for me to do myself due to the 6 character minimum

Comment: Well after a little readin it seems GCD is indeed the new and shiny way to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: The disadvantage of performSelector variants is that it limits the possible method signatures that could be used. It wasn't a problem here, but if you needed to call two methods, or a method with 3 parameters, you wouldn't be able to do it with performSelector.  Otherwise, in this case, a delay of 0.0 is essentially the same (runs ASAP, but during the next run loop)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the animation. One is being done while another is not yet finished (moving & deleting animation) causing one cell to be drawn upon the other. You can verify this by moving the cells around again. The correct order will then be displayed.  According to Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1) on the UITableView:

> Note: The data source should not call setEditing:animated: from within its implementation of tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:. If for some reason it must, it should invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.

Therefore to fix this, do this to your code:

```
if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: fromIndexPath.section] == 0) {
   [self performSelector:@selector(someMethod:) withObject:fromIndexPath afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void) someMethod:(NSIndexPath *) fromIndexPath {
[self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Should work fine. Just change the delay to something shorter that suites you.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that your rows or what's inside them can take focus, have you checked that you have called `resignFirstResponder` or `[view endEditing:YES]`? We saw this when we used text fields and (IIRC it was iOS 4 version dependent too) left the focus in one of the fields.

Comment: I made sure my test project didn't include anything like this (just added).  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the tableview after deleting the section. Try this code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *fromArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section]; 
    NSMutableArray *toArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.section];

    NSString *movedObject = [[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section] objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    [fromArray removeObject:movedObject];
    [toArray insertObject:movedObject atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

        if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: fromIndexPath.section] == 0) {
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't want to lose the animations, and it doesn't explain the behavior I am seeing.  Elsewhere in my application I am able to delete sections with animation just fine, it's only when I try to do so inside the moveRow method that I am finding an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of `fromArray` and `toArray` in your code. If the item has a retain count of 1 prior to removing it from the array, it will have a retain count of 0 before adding it to `toArray`.

If you swap the order, the item will go from retain count of 1 to 2 then back to 1 when the remove is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this didn't seem to make any difference. I am using ARC, if it is of consequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UITableViewRowAnimationFade animation is interfering with the UITableViewCell move animation. One thing you can try is to delay the section deletion a little bit late in order for the cell move row animation to finish.

Try replace your code with the following code.

```
-(void)deleteSection:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet
{
    [self.tableView deleteSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *fromArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section]; 
    NSMutableArray *toArray = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.section];

    NSString *movedObject = [[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section] objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    [fromArray removeObject:movedObject];
    [toArray insertObject:movedObject atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: fromIndexPath.section] == 0) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(deleteSection:) withObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section] afterDelay:1.0];
//      [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution that lost animation on last row :

```
if([listOfItemsOnTransaction count]==indexPath.row){ 
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]     
   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   }else
   {
       [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] 
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


   }
```